# c# create process inside form and monitor activity

Tags: c#, process

I need to run a program, and in case the program is not used for over 20 minutes, close it.
My main idea involved creating a process inside of a c# window application form, and use the form to (de)activate in order to tell when the app is not in focus.
unfortunately when the inner process is focused(for example: notepad.exe ran inside a windows form) the form is considered not Active.

My code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT Rect);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
            p.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            p.Start();
            IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
            RECT pRect = d ;
            Size cSize = new Size();
            GetWindowRect(handle, ref pRect);
            cSize.Width = pRect.right - pRect.left;
            cSize.Height = pRect.bottom - pRect.top;

            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Interval = 7000;
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = false;

            MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.Deactivate event.");
            this.Activated += Form1_Activated;
            this.Deactivate += Form1_Deactivate;
        }
        private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.Deactivate event.");
        }
        private void Form1_Deactivate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            //MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.Deactivate event.");

        }
        private void Form1_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            // MessageBox.Show("hiya .");
        }
    }

}
```

can someone point out how to do this(e.g:perhaps enclosing the process inside a panel,and using the panel's activate or deactivate?)

Comment: I believe you can use Timer class.

Comment: i am using Timer class.my problem is in the way i detect the app is not valid:when the focus is on the app inside("notepad.exe") - and not in the form behind it - the form is considred deactivated(and the form1_deactivate is called).i want to spot only when the app itself(the entire window of the app) is deactivated.

Comment: does anyone know the answer?